# Date Format changed to 'mm/dd/yyyy' from 'dd/mm/yyyy' in Excel to CSV Convertion

Tags: vb.net, excel, date, csv

I am using `VB.Net` (Dot net version 3.5) and `Office 2007` installed in my system. I am converting a `excel file to csv` using the following coding

```
  Dim xlBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = Nothing
  Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = Nothing
  xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
  Dim xlSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
  Dim xRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = Nothing

  xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(D:\items.xls, True) 

  xlSheet = xlBook.ActiveSheet
  xRange = xlSheet.UsedRange

  xlSheet.SaveAs(Filename:="D:\sheet1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True,
  ReadOnlyRecommended:=True) 
  xlBook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
```

In the above items excel file, the date column has value `31-07-2015`. But after converting to csv. The converted csv file has the value `07/31/2015`. Can anyone help me what's wrong with generating the csv file.

Comment: Date "formats" are how dates are displayed to people.  Dates do not have a format.  When you set a column format that is also just how it is displayed to you.  When you save to csv it apparently saves as Invariant Culture so whatever might import it doesnt have to know what the format is

Comment: @user3697824 is partially correct; it is important to denote the difference in Display Formats and Serialized DataType Formats

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I think this is a huge bug in .Net. One solution I would recommend assuming you are converting from one to another, is to import Excel file as a dataset in .Net first, then output it as CSV file, making sure a ' is placed in front of the dates in the date column. Preventing .Net from changing its order between day and month to American format.